# How to #import File Declare Globle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can u Give me the exact solution of that problem :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
```

I need to prevent from re-writing the import code in each file. Is there any way to declare the import package code in global file, and use / extent the particular file accordingly.